# A word that refers to saying something in an attempt to anger or embarrass someone into doing something that they don’t want to do?

Tags: single-word-requests

I’m looking for a word to refer to the act of trying to embarrass someone to the point that they do something they don’t want to do.

Example: Let’s say all of your friends are jumping off of a cliff into a lake, but you don’t want to, for whatever reason. One friend remains at the top with you, trying to convince you to jump. One tactic they use is to try and embarrass you enough or anger you into doing it by saying something along the lines of - “So, basically, you’re too chicken to jump, right?”

I believe I could use the phrase ‘egg on’ for this, but would rather have a singular, more specific word for it. I’m pretty sure there is one, but I just can’t bring it to mind. I’ve considered ‘reverse psychology’, too, but it just doesn’t fit what I’m trying to say.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

In addition to Marcellothearcane's excellent answer I suggest **goad**.

From Lexico:

> [**Goad**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/goad)
>   VERB
>
> 1. Provoke or annoy (someone) so as to stimulate some action or reaction.
>      *‘He was trying to goad her into a fight.’*

The word derives from a spiked stick used to push cattle along.  This definitely provides that same subtext that you're seeking to add.

Comment: I was going to say "prod", but "goad" is much better, yes.

Answer (score 57):

The word that springs to mind is **provoke**:

> - stimulate or give rise to (a reaction or emotion, typically a strong or unwelcome one) in someone.
> - deliberately make (someone) annoyed or angry.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/provoke)

It is used to signify a successful provocation (when someone responds), and also the act of provoking, which may or may not yield results:

> - *‘Sometimes applicants are deliberately provoked to see how they handle themselves.’*
> - *‘Rachel refused to be provoked’*

Synonyms include *incense, enrage, irritate, infuriate, exasperate, exacerbate, madden, pique, nettle*.

Comment: ‘Provoke’ is a good suggestion, as well. I’ve chosen to use ‘goad’, though, as it fits perfectly in my context. Adding your list of synonyms to the brain pan for later use, since ‘to goad’ is a type of provocation.

Comment: Great answers.  Less fancy: _push_, _pressure_ (touching on _peer pressure_), maybe even _bully_.  Reminds me of third grade and _Back to the Future_.

Comment: _Antagonize_ came to mind immediately, but your _provoke_ I think is more on point...

Answer (score 33):

Another option would be to '**needle**' someone into doing something:

- incite to action by repeated gibes e.g. "needled the boy into a fight"

[https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/needle]

Answer (score 21):

I think "***incite***" can also work in your context -

## Incite

> : to encourage someone to do something violent, illegal, or unpleasant, especially by making them angry (or excited).

Example sentences -

> 1. *The rock band's failure to show up **incited** a riot, as the crowd had waited for hours.*
> 2. *He **incited** the workforce to go on strike.*

([Source](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/incite))

Comment: Incite is good if your target is a crowd (as in your examples), goad would be better for individuals.

Answer (score 17):

How about [bait](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bait)?

3. b. entice, lure

Comment: Frankly I think that definitions 1 and 2 are a better match. The vitum of a bear baiting was often in a cage and had to be angered enough that they would emerge and expose their flanks.

Comment: This is the first word I thought of reading the question.  In this sense it's not related to the antiquated practice of "bear baiting" and more related to the practice of fishing, as in "fishing for a compliment".  Your "friend" on the cliff is "fishing for your jump", they keep dangling various things in front of you hoping one of them will get you to "bite" and "take the bait" and jump.

Comment: I immediately thought of bait in this way but none of the definitions matched my expectation. Thank you both for clarifying it, I will try to update this post soon.

Answer (score 12):

There are some good options here, but the first word that came to mind was **taunt**:

> : to reproach or challenge in a mocking or insulting manner

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/taunt)

Answer (score 10):

The word that (very) closely suits your context is -

## Pique

> : to excite or arouse especially by a provocation, challenge, or
> rebuff sly remarks to pique their curiosity
>
> : to arouse anger or resentment in: [IRRITATE](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/irritate)

([Meriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pique))

Example sentences ([credit](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/513383/a-word-that-refers-to-saying-something-in-an-attempt-to-anger-or-embarrass-someo/513541#513541)) -

> 1. *The cowardly duke was **piqued** into joining the king's expeditionary forces.*
> 2. *Although he wasn't planning on attending prom, James was **piqued** into it by his friends.*
> 3. *We **piqued** Jessie into joining the protest.*

Answer (score 9):

Since you seem mostly focused on being 'embarrassed' into action, you could say 'shame (into)'.

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/shame-into

> to make someone feel so guilty or embarrassed that they do what you want

Examples:

- The cowardly duke was shamed into joining the king's expeditionary forces.
- Although he wasn't planning on attending prom, James was shamed into it by his friends.
- We shamed Jessie into joining the protest.

Answer (score 6):

For the moment I can think of **instigate**.

> : to goad or urge forward  : PROVOKE

Merriam-Webster 11th Collegiate Dictionary

> to cause an event or situation to happen by making a set of actions or a formal process begin:

[Cambridge online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/instigate)

Comment: I don't think instigate fits at all. "Instigate" means to begin something yourself, whereas the question is looking for a word for convincing somebody else to do something, such as might fit in the sentence "I [verb]ed him to do it" (where "instigate" definitely doesn't fit).

Comment: 'Instigate' is a transitive verb. You can instigate another person to do something (usually bad). SOED provides an example: <You must not instigate your elders to a breach of faith>

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the verb "to bully" could be appropriate in this case.
[Lexico Bully](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/bully)

As in "The people he thought were his friends bullied him into jumping to his death."

The Lexico link also offers the word "coerce".  Which is a milder form.

Answer (score 1):

How about **importune**?

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/importune)
>
> 1a : to press or urge with troublesome persistence
> b archaic : to request or beg for urgently

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the specifics, you might simply use "pressure". Peer pressure is generally a form of shaming; if you don't do it, you're not "cool".  (Or in this instance, if you don't do it, you're chicken.)

"Shame (into)" is another good one, though a somewhat different meaning. Shaming is more a sense that if you don't do the thing, it's a moral failure. It would depend on your exact context.